# Suppose $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges and $b_n\gt 0$, show that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{1+b_n}$ also diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As the title says, given a series $b_n > 0$, where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ is divergent:

Show that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{1+b_n}$$
is also divergent.

So I've defined the series as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n v_n$ where $u_n = b_n$ and $v_n = \frac {1}{1+b_n}$.

I'm sure there was some sort of convergence test which stipulated that for a product of two series, if one diverges the entire thing does, however I might be mistaken. If so, how do I properly prove this?

Comment: [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952644/if-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-dfraca-n1a-n-0-then-displaystyle) This may helps you to understand André Nicolas's answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131678/321264

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the sequence $(b_n)$ is unbounded, then $\frac{b_n}{1+b_n}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ for infinitely many $n$. So in particular $\frac{b_n}{1+b_n}$ does not have limit $0$, and therefore the series $\sum \frac{b_n}{1+b_n}$ diverges.

If on the other hand the sequence $(b_n)$ is bounded above by $B$, then $\frac{b_n}{1+b_n}\ge \frac{1}{B+1}b_n$ for all $n$, so by Comparison the series $\sum \frac{b_n}{1+b_n}$ diverges.

Comment: I should've mentioned that the problem specified that $b_n$ was bounded. So the latter explanation makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The result does not require boundedness, so it is a good thing that you did not mention it.