# If $\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}{b_n}$ is divergent, then so is $\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\dfrac{b_n}{1+b_n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to prove the following:

**Suppose $\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}{b_n}$ is divergent. Then $\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\dfrac{b_n}{1+b_n}}$ is divergent.**

I think you have to prove by contradiction and by using Cauchy's criterion. But how to start with that? Or is it possible to use another well-known criterion?

Comment: don't we have $b_n$ conv/div $\implies 1/b_n$ div/conv

Comment: no, consider the harmonic series

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: You only have that if $\sum b_n$ converges, then $b_n \to 0$, so $\dfrac 1 {b_n} \not\to 0$, so necessarily $\sum \dfrac 1 {b_n}$ diverges.

Comment: Do we know that $b_n \ge 0 \ \forall n$?

Comment: Put $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $n\geq 1$, Then $u_n$ is a convergent series. If $b_n=\frac{u_n}{1-u_n}$, using $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+O(x^2)$, we have $b_n=u_n+\frac{1}{n}+O(1/n^{3/2})$, and we see that the series $b_n$ is divergent. But the series $b_n/(1+b_n)=u_n$ is a convergent series.

Comment: $$b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt{n}-(-1)^n}\implies\sum_nb_n\ \text{diverges},\ \sum_n\frac{b_n}{1+b_n}\ \text{converges}$$

Comment: @Did: Your counterexample and the one of Kelenner show that the OP has most probably missed the hypothesis that $b_n \ge 0 \ \forall n$, in which case the question has an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212473/suppose-sum-n-1-infty-b-n-diverges-for-b-n-0-show-that-the-series), so I voted to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel fischer noted this argument only works for the special case of non negative terms $b_i $.

Hint: if the set $\{n: b_n \geq 1\} $ is infinite then you should know what to do. However if that is finite,then try to make use of the following fact:

for every  $n $ such that  $b_n<1$ we have

$$\frac {b_n}{1+b_n} > \frac {b_n}{2} $$

Comment: That argument works for $b_n \geqslant 0$, but not if the $b_n$ can have different signs.

Comment: @ Daniel fischer I see. For some reason I assumed that the terms of the series are non negative

Comment: I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

**I have an answer when the limit of $b_{n}$ does exist and $b_{n}>0$.**

We know that 
$\sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}{b_n}$
is divergent so
If 
$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}b_{n}\neq 0$
so 
$ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\dfrac{b_n}{1+b_n}\neq 0. $
And if
$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}b_{n}= 0$
so we apply the limit test for series
$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{b_n}{1+b_n}}{b_{n}}=1 $
which tells us the 
$ \sum_\limits{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\dfrac{b_n}{1+b_n}}$
is divergent.

Comment: @Amr I assumed the both condition one time zero and one time non zero. I think it is true.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. First, the limit test only works for series with positive terms, which is not necessarily the context here. Second, if $b_n \not\to 0$, how do you deduce that $\dfrac {b_n} {1 + b_n} \not\to 0$? Third, who says that $b_n$ is supposed to have a limit?

Comment: I said that $b_n$ might not have a limit *at all*: think about $(-1)^n$ or $\sin n$.

Comment: @AlexM. OK Now I got u. So I edit the answer.

Comment: No, it is still wrong: $(-1)^n n$ has no limit, but $\dfrac {(-1)^n n} {1 + (-1)^n n} \to 1$. What you want is to show that if $b_n$ has no limit, then $\dfrac {b_n} {1 + b_n} \not\to 0$; how do you do that?

Comment: @AlexM. I edited the answer again. We should prove that if the $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b_{n}$ does not exist then  $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\dfrac{b_n}{1+b_n}$ does not convergent to zero.